# Which option to choose for writing CSV file in Spark (HDFS)?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, dataframe, hdfs

I have to compare CSV files and then I have to delete all duplicate rows. So, my condition is like I have one folder and I have to put every filtered result in that folder, and when some new file will come I have to compare the existing files in the folder with the new one and finally, I have to put back the result to the same folder.

> ```
> eg: /data/ingestion/file1.csv
>
>    a1 b1 c1
>
>    a2 b2 c2
>
>    a3 b3 c3
>
> /data/ingestion/file2.csv
>
>    a4 b4 c4
>
>    a5 b5 c5
>
>    a6 b6 c6
>
> new upcoming file(upcoming_file.csv):
>
>    a1 b1 c1
>
>    a5 b5 c5
>
>    a7 b7 c7
> ```

Now my approach is creating one dataframe from all the files present in /data/ingestion/*. Then creating one dataframe of upcoming_file.csv and appending both of them using union operation. Finally, applying distinct transformation.
Now I have to write it back to /data/ingestion making sure that no duplicity will be there. So, I choose overwrite operation.

```
deleted_duplicate.write
  .format("csv")
  .mode("overwrite")
  .save("hdfs://localhost:8020/data/ingestion/")
```

Then I finally end up deleting everything inside the folder /data/ingestion.
Even the new dataframe is not getting written in CSV files.

I have tried other options also but I have not achieved what I have explained above!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to write output to new directory on hdfs - in case of processing failure you will always be able to discard whatever was processed and launch processing from scratch with original data - it's safe and easy. :)

When the processing is complete - just delete old one and rename new one to the name of the old one.

**UPDATE:**

```
deleted_duplicate.write
  .format("csv")
  .mode("overwrite")
  .save("hdfs://localhost:8020/data/ingestion_tmp/")

   Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    conf.set("fs.hdfs.impl",org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.class.getName());
    conf.set("fs.file.impl",org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalFileSystem.class.getName());
    FileSystem  hdfs = FileSystem.get(URI.create("hdfs://<namenode-hostname>:<port>"), conf);
    hdfs.delete("hdfs://localhost:8020/data/ingestion", isRecusrive);
    hdfs.rename("hdfs://localhost:8020/data/ingestion_tmp", "hdfs://localhost:8020/data/ingestion");
```

[Here](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.1.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html) is link to HDFS FileSystem API docs

Comment: Yes, this will be an option. For curiosity: is it possible to do so?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Why shouldn't it be possible?

Comment: Definitely I'll be asking for the solution against the claim. Not just the claim :)

Comment: and none of the option is working. So, how is it possible there are four options I have tried all of them